# How to display array based on date in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
const data1 = [
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-14 00:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      }
    ];

    const data2 = [
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-12 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-11 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
    ]

    const arr = new Array();

    arr.push(data1, data2);


    arr.forEach(server => {
      const rec = orderBy(server, ['dateStart'], ['desc']);

  console.log(rec);
    });
  }
```

What I want is if the data1 have an array(16) then the data2 have an array(20) and both them have the same date but the data2 have oldest data that shouldn't display.

output should be like this:

```
[
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-14 00:00:01",
    name: "Server1"
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
    name: "Server1"
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
    name: "Server1"
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
    name: "Server1"
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
    name: "Server1"
  }
],
[
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
    name: 'Server2'
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
    name: 'Server2'
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
    name: 'Server2'
  },
  {
    dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
    name: 'Server2'
  }
]
```

here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akhhbp

if there's a new array. which is the data3 and it has an array(25) then it will compare each other. like data1, data2 and data3 if there date doesn't match it will not display.

example:

```
data1 = [{
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      }]
    data2 = [ {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-12 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      }],
    data3 = [ {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server3'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:12:01",
        name: 'Server3'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server3'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server3'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-12 10:00:01",
        name: 'Server3'
      }]
```

the output should be.

```
[{
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
            name: 'Server1'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
            name: 'Server1'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
            name: 'Server1'
          }],
 [ {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
            name: 'Server2'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
            name: 'Server2'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
            name: 'Server2'
          }],
[ {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
            name: 'Server3'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:12:01",
            name: 'Server3'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
            name: 'Server3'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
            name: 'Server3'
          },
          {
            dateStart: "2020-02-12 10:00:01",
            name: 'Server3'
          }]
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking, could you give an example with smaller arrays (of size 2 and 3 for example)?

Comment: quite confusing :-(

Comment: @kaushik sorry about that sir. example sir the data1(3) [{...},{...},{...}] then the data2(5)[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}] then it will display when the data1 or data2 have the same year-month-day. or when there's a new array which is the data3(3) [{...},{...},{...}] its similar it will compare if there's a similar year-month-day then it will display

Answer (score 2):

I will put up the solution this way -

- Before merging the arrays, sort them if they are not sorted (descending order). Use `array.sort()` for it.
- For merging, put the first array `data1` in a new array, and save the last record for this array in temp variable. `let temp = data1[data1.length -1].dateStart`. Because you don't need data from other arrays older than this date.
- Iterate over remaining arrays `data2, data3, ...` and push the data in a new array if the `dateStart` is not older than `temp`.

Comment: Sorting data1 by dateStart `data1.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.dateStart).getTime() - new Date(b.dateStart).getTime())`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save your data like this all you need is using spread operator `(...)` like so :

```
const data1 = [
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-14 00:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server1'
      }
    ];

    const data2 = [
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 14:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 13:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 12:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-13 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-12 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
      {
        dateStart: "2020-02-11 11:00:01",
        name: 'Server2'
      },
    ]

let final = [[...data1] , [...data2] , ... more arrays];
```

and the output is :

```
[ [ { dateStart: '2020-02-14 00:00:01', name: 'Server1' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 14:00:01', name: 'Server1' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 13:00:01', name: 'Server1' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 12:00:01', name: 'Server1' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 11:00:01', name: 'Server1' } ],
  [ { dateStart: '2020-02-13 14:00:01', name: 'Server2' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 13:00:01', name: 'Server2' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 12:00:01', name: 'Server2' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-13 11:00:01', name: 'Server2' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-12 11:00:01', name: 'Server2' },
    { dateStart: '2020-02-11 11:00:01', name: 'Server2' } ] ]
```